# KDB & HTML/CSS: How to bold text of the first column of table?

Tags: html, css, formatting, styles, kdb

I am auto-generating the HTML output using KDB. I would like to avoid labeling the html with classes if possible because I'd rather not re-work the KDB code. I tried using first-child, but it didn't work. Any other suggestions?

**KDB:**

```
.util.html.t:{[t]
  if[not type[t] in 98 99h; :"Result not a table type!"];
  r:"<table cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='2'>";
  r:r,"<tr class='title'>";
  r:r,(,/){"<th>",x,"</th>"} each string cols t;
  r:r,"</tr>";
  r:r,(,/){"<tr>",((,/){
    if[type[x]=type[""]; x:`$x];
    if[not type[x]=type[enlist ""]; 
      x:string x;
      if[x like "*[0-9]%"; :"<td class=\"centeralignum\">",x,"</td>"];
      ];
    if[type[x]=type[enlist ""]; x:"," sv x];
    :"<td>",x,"</td>";
  } each x),"</tr>"} each 0!t;
  r:r,"</table>";
  :r;
  }
```

**CSS:**

```
     h3 { font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Calibri } 
     body { font-size: 12px; font-family: Calibri } 
     tr.title { background: lightblue repeat-x left bottom; font-weight: bold; border: 1px solid #000000;} 
     th {border: 1px solid black;}
     table { border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}
     table td {border-left: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black; width:125px;}
     table td:first-child {font-weight: bold;}
     td.centeralignum {text-align: center}
```

**HTML**

```
<table cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='2'><tr class='title'><th>name</th><th>a</th><th>b</th><th>c</th></tr><tr><td>bob</td><td>1</td><td>4</td><td>7</td></tr><tr><td>anna</td><td>2</td><td>5</td><td>8</td></tr><tr><td>ray</td><td>3</td><td>6</td><td>9</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the HTML and CSS on Firefox that you gave worked for me. I even toggled the first-child property to make sure that it was causing it which it was. The first-child property has been supported for quite a while but it is worth checking [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) to see if your browser supports it.

You can go into developer tools on your browser and select the element in the inspector to see the styles that are being applied. If they are being overridden they will have a strikethough and you can also toggle properties or add new ones in the developer tools to see how they change the display